# Can't execute external program through system()?

Tags: php, system, external

I tried to compile my latex file in php script, but it can't call `xelatex`.

In php script:

```
system("/usr/bin/whoami");
system("/usr/bin/xelatex foo.tex 2>&1");
```

output:

```
myuser
sh: 1: /usr/bin/xelatex: not found
```

But in my terminal:

```
$ /usr/bin/whoami
=> myuser
$ /usr/bin/xelatex foo.tex
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.2-0.9995.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
...(successful output)...
```

I run php as `myuser`, and pass `system()` absolute path. And I turn `safe_mode` off. Why can't I still execute external programs?

Comment: What is chown and chgrp of you php file ? and also permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I contacted my system administrator and found the problem. The machine is in a NFS, so the `apache` and login shell is on different machines. There is no `xelatex` on the machine where apache is running.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permission of the directory from where you running you PHP code. check for myuser permissions

just for verification try it with root.

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not the file 'foo.tex' which it is unable to find? Try having the shell output to a file, e.g. `system("/usr/bin/xelatex ./foo.tex > ./test.out");` and see what luck you get then.